# AngularJS: Google Map Not Appearing

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use [Angularjs-Google-Maps](http://ngmap.github.io/) in comibination with ui-router. I'm getting a weird issue where the map is only partially appearing.

I've managed to resolve it by creating a directive that triggers a 'resize' event to repaint the map:

```
function autoRefresh() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
          google.maps.event.trigger(scope.map, 'resize');
          console.log("this works!");
      });
    }
  }
}

<map center="-34.397, 150.644" zoom="8" auto-refresh></map>
```

And this works great, once the initial page has loaded and I change the state, the map appears. But if I simply do a hard reload of the page in the browser, the map doesn't appear. I have to change the state before the map is visible.

Is there an alternative to '$stateChangeSuccess' that works on initial page load?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ran into this problem and it was due to including the traditional google maps api script in my main app.html page. If that is loading first, then angular-google-maps tries to load the service, it will choke. Basically the async call to load the google maps script can only happen once. Not sure if that's what's happening to you, but just a thought.

Comment: Btw, I ended up moving over to angular-google-maps-native and found it to be *far* less finicky than any of the others.